# How do I know if I should use VBUS-sensing on STM32?

Tags: usb, stm32, usb-device

I have a schematic that looks like this.

[image]

And I wonder if I need VBUS-sensing on my STM32? Because, I planning to use the +5V from the USB, to power the STM32 and also have communication (D+, D-) with the computer and the STM32. **Is that possible even if I power the STM32 with USB-power?**

According to VBUS-sensing detection data sheet from ST. They say that if USB device is bus-powered, then I don't need VBUS-sensing. **Is my STM32 the USB-device or what?**

Assume that I'm using VBUS-sensing, **what should it be good for?**

Should I connect VBUS directly to PA9 (with a voltage divider) and let it just float? No connection and no CubeMX configuration?

My STM32 is STM32F373 series.

[image]

Comment: You need Vbus sensing if your device is capable of continuing to operate without USB plugged in (so it has its own power source separate from the USB input) *AND* your device needs to know when the USB cable has been unplugged. If your device is only USB powered, or it doesn't care if the cable is unplugged, then you probably don't need Vbus sensing.

Comment: @brhans Thank you! So, the STM32 have a special pin, called PA9. And when that got 3.3-4.0V, then the STM32 knows that "Now USB is connected"? No configuration in CubeMX? Just let PA9 be connected to VBUS?

Comment: You should ALWAYS use VBUS sensing on any USB device. If the device is bus-powered, this requirement is satisfied automatically. Otherwise you MUST use some sort of VBUS sense to gate premature pull-up on D+.

Comment: @Ale..chenski I have a 1.5 kOhm resistor on D+ and my USB device is bus-powered. In other words, I'm using VBUS to power my STM32.

Comment: There still might be problems if your device takes a long time to boot, and USB SIE is not ready for communication fro a while. If your pull-up comes from VBUS right away, the host might try to enumerate your device and will fail, then mark the port as "dead".

Comment: Okej. I don't know. Haven't done this before. I just followed ST's own manual AN4879 with an example where VBUS powers the STM32 device and the STM32 device has communication with the computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do VBUS sensing if you have another power source.

If your device is bus powered only, all it could tell you is that you have no power, but the MCU isn't running at this point either, because it has no power.

If you have a separate power source, you need to reset the USB state machines (and possibly some other logic) when VBUS goes away, because for a surprise eject, no configuration change is sent, but on reconnection, your device must be inactive before it is enumerated and configured.

Comment: And PA9 is the pin for resetting the USB logic? No configuration in CubeMX?

Comment: VBUS sensing is fixed to this pin, and always connected. You need to take care not to assign any other function to it, especially not one that uses alternate function routing, and you need a voltage divider to stay inside the maximum ratings if the MCU is unpowered, but VBUS is +5V.

Comment: Has PA9 some kind of start up sequence? When it got high voltage (3.3V), then it tell the STM32 that the USB can be used. In this case, my USB pepherial is FS at my STM32.